# how to change the UIBarButtonItem button design?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I am newbie for iPhone application.

What I have is as below.

```
UIBarButtonItem *flipButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                           initWithTitle:@"Flip"                                            
                           style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                           target:self 
                           action:@selector(flipView)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = flipButton;
[flipButton release];
```

BUT, problem is button design. It is just square button.

How can I make this button to same as Back button?

Any idea/ suggestion would be appreciated.

---

I was trying with

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = @"Back";
self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(goBackToSAMA:)] autorelease];
```

but its working working. Not working means, `goBackToSAMA` is not getting invoked and button text is also not coming to `Back`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, ther is only one way how to display the standard back button. **You have to push** `UINavigationItem` in `UINavigationBar`. Or better: there need to be navigation **item to be popped**.

---

***IMPORTANT:** This will not work nice with `UINavigationController`'s bar, so use your own!*

```
UINavigationItem *firstItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Go Back"];
UINavigationItem *secondItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Something"];

navigationBar.items = @[ firstItem, secondItem ];
```

This code will display *“Something”* as a title and to the left, there will be back button saying *“Go Back”*. By default it shows the title of previous item, but you can customize it:

```
firstItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Another Title" 
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:nil
                                                            selector:nil];
```

Note that the target and selector are `nil`. You **can not** customize the action of back button like this, because it is special. You will need to implement protocol `UINavigationBarDelegate` and this method:

```
– (BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)bar shouldPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item {
    [self doYourActionHere];
    return NO; // Returning YES, would trigger pop animation.
}
```

---

Or just use custom background image…
[image: system back button background]

Comment: I went ahead with Square button.

Answer (score 1):

One possiblity might be to change the back bar button via this method:

[`backButtonBackgroundImageForState: barMetrics:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/backButtonBackgroundImageForState%3abarMetrics%3a)

Another possibility might be to replace the "`backBarButtonItem`" with a custom view.

If you want to roll your own custom bar button item, the option you're looking for is the "`UIBarButtonItem`" method "[`initWithCustomView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithCustomView%3a)", and that's where you can put in designs of your choosing.

Comment: I don't want to use the image. As xcode default have back button, I want to use same. I don't want to create image for button and use that...